How to identify the command behind a file descriptor created with `exec`?
This command opens a file descriptor:
exec 77> /home/admin/somefile

However, when I check with lsof, it only shows me that it's bash:

admin@i-0a8158ef4cb3362f5:\~$ lsof somefile 

COMMAND PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME

bash    811 admin   77w   REG  259,1        0 272875 somefile


admin@i-0a8158ef4cb3362f5:/proc/811$ ls -l fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 admin admin 64 Aug 10 12:30 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 admin admin 64 Aug 10 12:30 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 admin admin 64 Aug 10 12:30 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 admin admin 64 Aug 10 12:30 255 -> /dev/pts/0
l-wx------ 1 admin admin 64 Aug 10 12:30 77 -> /home/admin/somefile

Is there a way to find out the exact command that created the file descriptor, and not just bash?
And one more thing: if someone executed the exec command and then cleared out the history, how can I possibly find out if the exec command was executed ?

exec is a bash builtin command (and has to be built in, to do its job); lsof shows it as opened by bash because it was opened by bash.

Possibly you're looking for the name of a script that includes the exec command in question, but if so then you have a misconception: that script is not the command that is running.  The script is input to bash, which is the command that is running, and therefore the one reported by lsof. It is the function of the shebang line that you must put at the top of such a script to tell the system what command to use to process the script. When you type the script's name as a command, the system runs the command from the shebang line and feeds the script to it as input.

So you have the PID of the bash process. The next step would be to find the command line beloinging to this PID. Of course, if the bash process gets its input via stdin, which is often the case, you are out of luck.

if there's auditing then it might be logged ( auditd service ), but you'll need to see if  you can set that level of granularity in the config

@user1934428 If it were getting its input via stdin, /proc/<pid>/0 would link to the script rather than the temrinal. Scripts are usually run as bash scriptname, not bash < scriptname. E.g. it's what happens if the script has a shebang.

@Barmar : I was thinking of the use with a #! line. In this case, the calling process would feed the script via stdin, and we can't see the path anymore. Or is this handled differently?

@user1934428 That's not how #! works, because then the script couldn't use read variable to read input from the terminal. It simply appends the script name to the command in the shebang. So if you have #!/bin/bash, executing the program is equivalent to executing /bin/bash scriptname

@Barmer: Thanks for the clarification. It makes sense to me. I just find then the explanation of the -s option confusing: If the -s option is present, or if no arguments remain  after  option  processing, then commands are read from the standard input. Would this then mean that the stdin is then not connected to the terminal anymore, once all options have been processed? This sounds odd to me.
